# Why python shows same index value for same character in a string?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to print all the occurences of character 'p' in a string "python program".It shows same index value as 0 both 'p's in the string instead of 0 and 7.

```
str = raw_input("enter a string:")
sub = raw_input("enter a sub string:")
for i in str:
    if i.lower() == sub.lower():
        print i, str.index(i)
```

Output :

```
enter a string:python program
enter a sub string:p
p 0
p 0
```

Comment: `str.index(i)` means "What is the first index that `i` occurs in `str`". How is going to return different values if you call it with the same argument? You should be using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) for your `for` loop instead.

Comment: So you call `str.index(i)` with `i` equal to `"p"` twice.  Why do you think it would give two different results?

Comment: Ok.. Got it.But am unable to write the same with enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for a solution:

```
sub = raw_input("enter the sub string you're looking for: ")
string = raw_input("enter the text you're looking in: ")

def get_next(text, sub):
    for i in range(len(text)+1):
        pos = text.find(sub, i)
        if pos == -1 :  #if no occurrences, do nothing  
            break
        if i == pos: #would print the sub and the pos only if pointer in correct position
            print sub, pos

get_next(string, sub)
```

You can have a while loop instead of a function, but I think a function would be more convenient if you want to use the code several times.